# How to execute the remaining code if there is any Exception in C# code?

Tags: c#

```
RegistryKey key10 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DiagTrack", true);
        RegistryKey key11 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\dmwappushservice", true);
        RegistryKey key12 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\diagsvc", true);
        RegistryKey key14 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\diagnosticshub.standardcollector.service", true);
        RegistryKey key15 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WdiServiceHost", true);
        RegistryKey key16 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WdiSystemHost", true);
        try
        {
            key10.SetValue("Start", 4, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            key11.SetValue("Start", 4, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            key12.SetValue("Start", 4, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            key14.SetValue("Start", 4, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            key15.SetValue("Start", 4, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            key16.SetValue("Start", 4, RegistryValueKind.DWord);

        }

        catch(Exception)
        {

        }

        finally
        {
            key10?.Dispose();
            key11?.Dispose();
            key12?.Dispose();
            key14?.Dispose();
            key15?.Dispose();
            key16?.Dispose();
        }
```

What I want to do here is that while the compiler tries the code in the try method and if it finds any exception, then it should execute the rest of the code in the try method instead of just ignoring all of the code.

Comment: It feels like you try mitigating symptoms instead of addressing the cause of the exceptions. Why does your code throw exceptions in the first place? What is the nature of these exceptions? Possibly, with a more defensive design of your code you could avoid the exceptions being thrown...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
            string[] keys = {
                 @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DiagTrack",
                 @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\dmwappushservice",
                 @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\diagsvc",
                 @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\diagnosticshub.standardcollector.service",
                 @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WdiServiceHost",
                 @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WdiSystemHost"
                            };

            foreach (string key in keys)
            {
                RegistryKey newKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(key, true);
                try
                {
                    newKey.SetValue("Start", 4, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }
```

Comment: `using RegistryKey newKey =...`

Comment: Your Code is working!                                                                                   What will be the code if I want to Get the value of all the keys instead of Setting the values. The value should be stored like uint value = Convert.ToUInt32(newKey.GetValue("Start")); The value of first key should be value1, second should be value2, and so on?

Comment: I would create a dictionary with the key of the dictionary being the key name and the value being the value that you read.

Comment: Could you pls answer with the code for this?

Comment: Like any dictionary : object value = dict[SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DiagTrack]

Answer (score 2):

There is no `On Error Resume Next` in C#. Instead: make each individual piece not fail. For example, you could do:

```cs
static bool TryDoTheThing(string path) {
    try {
        using var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(path, true);
        key.SetValue("Start", 4, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        return true;
    } catch {
        return false;
    }
}
TryDoTheThing(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DiagTrack");
TryDoTheThing(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\dmwappushservice");
TryDoTheThing(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\diagsvc");
TryDoTheThing(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\diagnosticshub.standardcollector.service");
TryDoTheThing(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WdiServiceHost");
TryDoTheThing(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WdiSystemHost");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the keys into an array then iterate one by one

```
RegistryKey[] keys = new RegistryKey[]
{
    Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DiagTrack", true),
    Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\dmwappushservice", true),
    Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\diagsvc", true),
    Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\diagnosticshub.standardcollector.service", true),
    Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WdiServiceHost", true),
    Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WdiSystemHost", true)
};

for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
{
    try
    {
        keys[i].SetValue("Start", 4, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {

    }
}
```

To Read

```
           Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            foreach (string key in keys)
            {
                RegistryKey rkey =  Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(key, true);
                dict.Add(key, rkey.GetValue("Start", RegistryValueKind.DWord));
                
            }
```

Comment: What will be the code if I want to Get the value of all the keys instead of Setting the values. The value should be stored like                                                                  uint value = Convert.ToUInt32(newKey.GetValue("Start"));    The value of first key should be value1, second should be value2, and so on?

Comment: Declare another array of `uint` and save there.

Comment: @jdweng How will I access those values in the dictionary?